# Step definition is not connecting with feature file in cucumber, selenium code

Tags: selenium, cucumber

1) When running the TestRunner to execute the test, the feature file is not connecting with Step Definition code and giving following message:

```
    Feature: Post text Hello Sakshi on Sakshi facebook account

      Scenario: Login sucessfully on Facebook application [90m# MyApplication.feature:2[0m
        [33mGiven [0m[33mOpen Facebook application[0m
        [33mWhen [0m[33mEnter valid id and password[0m
        [33mAnd [0m[33mClick on Login button[0m
        [33mThen [0m[33mFacebook home page should open[0m

      Scenario: Type text Sakshi Tyagi in search box [90m# MyApplication.feature:8[0m
        [33mGiven [0m[33mUser on Facebook home page[0m
        [33mWhen [0m[33mEnter text Sakshi Tyagi in search box[0m
        [33mAnd [0m[33mClick search button[0m
        [33mThen [0m[33mProfile of Sakshi should open[0m

      Scenario: Type text Hello Sakshi in post box [90m# MyApplication.feature:14[0m
        [33mGiven [0m[33mUser in Sakshi s facebook page[0m
        [33mWhen [0m[33mEnter text Hello Sakshi in search box[0m
        [33mAnd [0m[33mClick post button[0m
        [33mThen [0m[33mMessage should post to Sakshi[0m

    3 Scenarios ([33m3 undefined[0m)
    12 Steps ([33m12 undefined[0m)
    0m0.000s


    You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:

    @Given("^Open Facebook application$")
    public void open_Facebook_application() throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        throw new PendingException();
    }

    @When("^Enter valid id and password$")
    public void enter_valid_id_and_password() throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        throw new PendingException();
    }

    @When("^Click on Login button$")
    public void click_on_Login_button() throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        throw new PendingException();
    }

    @Then("^Facebook home page should open$")
    public void facebook_home_page_should_open() throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        throw new PendingException();
    }

    @Given("^User on Facebook home page$")
    public void user_on_Facebook_home_page() throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        throw new PendingException();
    }

    @When("^Enter text Sakshi Tyagi in search box$")
    public void enter_text_Sakshi_Tyagi_in_search_box() throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        throw new PendingException();
    }

    @When("^Click search button$")
    public void click_search_button() throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        throw new PendingException();
    }

    @Then("^Profile of Sakshi should open$")
    public void profile_of_Sakshi_should_open() throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        throw new PendingException();
    }

    @Given("^User in Sakshi s facebook page$")
    public void user_in_Sakshi_s_facebook_page() throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        throw new PendingException();
    }

    @When("^Enter text Hello Sakshi in search box$")
    public void enter_text_Hello_Sakshi_in_search_box() throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        throw new PendingException();
    }

    @When("^Click post button$")
    public void click_post_button() throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        throw new PendingException();
    }

    @Then("^Message should post to Sakshi$")
    public void message_should_post_to_Sakshi() throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        throw new PendingException();
    }
```

2) Feature file which contains the scenarios

```
            Feature: Post text Hello Sakshi on Sakshi facebook account
              Scenario: Login sucessfully on Facebook application
                Given Open Facebook application
                When Enter valid id and password
                And Click on Login button
                Then Facebook home page should open

              Scenario: Type text Sakshi Tyagi in search box
                Given User on Facebook home page
                When Enter text Sakshi Tyagi in search box
                And Click search button
                Then Profile of Sakshi should open

              Scenario: Type text Hello Sakshi in post box
                Given User in Sakshi s facebook page
                When Enter text Hello Sakshi in search box
                And Click post button
                Then Message should post to Sakshi
```

3) TestRunner:This is main master runner for the test

```
            package testRunner;

            import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
            import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
            import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

            @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
            @CucumberOptions( 
            plugin = {"pretty","html:target/cucumber-html-report"}, 
            features = {"features"},
            glue = {"classpath:src/stepDefiniction"},
            monochrome = false,
            strict = false,
            dryRun = false)

            public class TestRunnner {


            }
```

4) Step Definition: these are the main steps for browser automation

```
            package stepDefinition;

            import org.openqa.selenium.By;
            import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
            import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
            import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
            import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
            import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
            import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
            import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
            import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
            import cucumber.api.java.en.When;
            //import stepDefiniction.EncodingAndDecodingClass;

            public class StepDefinition {

                private static WebDriver driver = null ;
                //private static String decPassword = "SG90Zml4QDIyMg==";
                //String strPassword = EncodingAndDecodingClass.decodingMethod (decPassword);
                private static String password = "MindLift@xxx";
                WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
                WebElement waitElement;

            // First scenario
                @Given("^Open Facebook application$")
                public void open_Facebook_application() throws Throwable {
                    driver = new FirefoxDriver ();
                    driver.navigate().to("https://www.facebook.com/");
                    driver.manage().window().maximize();
                }

                @When("^Enter valid id and password$")
                public void enter_valid_id_and_password() throws Throwable {
                    driver.findElement(By.name("email")).clear();
                    driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys("rafiras16@gmail.com");
                    driver.findElement(By.name("pass")).clear();
                    driver.findElement(By.name("pass")).sendKeys(password);
                }

                @When("^Click on Login button$")
                public void click_on_Login_button() throws Throwable {
                    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[starts-with(@id,'u_0')]")).click();
                }

                @Then("^Facebook home page should open$")
                public void facebook_home_page_should_open() throws Throwable {
                    String strTitle = driver.getTitle();
                    System.out.print(strTitle);

                }

            // Second scenario
                @Given("^User on Facebook home page$")
                public void user_on_Facebook_home_page() throws Throwable {
                     waitElement= wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[(@class='_1frb') and (@name='q')]")) );

                }

                @When("^Enter text Sakshi Tyagi in search box$")
                public void enter_text_Sakshi_Tyagi_in_search_box() throws Throwable {
                     waitElement.clear();
                     waitElement.sendKeys("Sakshi Tyagi");

                }

                @When("^Click search button$")
                public void click_search_button() throws Throwable {
                    waitElement.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
                }

                @Then("^Profile of Sakshi should open$")
                public void profile_of_Sakshi_should_open() throws Throwable {

                }

            // Third scenario
                @Given("^User in Sakshi s facebook page$")
                public void user_in_Sakshi_s_facebook_page() throws Throwable {
                    waitElement= wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[(@class='_52eh _5bcu') and (text()='Sakshi Tyagi')]")) ); 
                    waitElement.click();
                }

                @When("^Enter text Hello Sakshi in search box$")
                public void enter_text_Hello_Sakshi_in_search_box() throws Throwable {
                    waitElement= wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@data-testid='status-attachment-mentions-input']")) ); 
                    waitElement.sendKeys("Hello ma'am");
                }

                @When("^Click post button$")
                public void click_post_button() throws Throwable {
                    waitElement= wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[(@type='submit') and (@data-testid='react-composer-post-button')]")));
                    waitElement.click();
                }

                @Then("^Message should post to Sakshi$")
                public void message_should_post_to_Sakshi() throws Throwable {}

            } // end of definition steps
```

5) Image for folder structure:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8OEx.jpg

Comment: Try with glue = "stepDefinition". Currently you have an extra 'c' in there.

Comment: I have removed that 'c' but still the problem is same. My "features/MyApplication.feature" in "CucumberProject" project folder only. Not able to find out the exact cause and have rebuild this twice but it don't work. Any help would be highly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Did u try the glue option i suggested? glue = "ste...."

Comment: Yes I tried the same glue = "stepDefinition" but problem is still same, kindly assist.

Comment: Try moving the feature file inside the src folder.

Comment: Still same issue after moving the feature file in src folder. I can send you the email for the snap shots for cucumber jars and this issue, if you want to check?

Comment: Can anybody help me out why this issue is occurring?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide complete feature file path in the runner class

```
package StepDefinition;

import java.io.File;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import com.cucumber.listener.Reporter;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;        
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber; 

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)  
@CucumberOptions(   
        features = {"src/test/resources/Features"}, 
        monochrome = true,
        plugin = {"pretty","junit:target/JUnitReports/report.xml",
                "json:target/JSONReports/report.json", 
                "html:target/HTMLReports"},
        glue={"StepDefinition"},
        strict = true,
       tags= {"@Login, @Home"}
       // ,dryRun = true
        )

public class RunnerClass {  
    public static void setUp() {
         
        System.out.println("Test Suite Execution Has Started");
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDown() {
        System.out.println("Test Suite Execution Completed.");
        //quitDriver();
        //SendEmail.sendEmailBody(TestData.Email.EMAIL_RESULT_SUBJECT1, "cucumber-json-report-SanityForTeamViewer");
         //Reporter.loadXMLConfig(new File("config/reports.xml"));
    }
}
```